# New environnement for colored background align

Tags: align, environments, backgrounds

I would like to have a specific environment for colored background equation.
However, Latex returns an error at the end of my new environment and I don't understand why.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload2]{empheq}
\usepackage{color}

%background color
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.8, .8, 1}
\newcommand*\mybluebox[1]{%
\colorbox{myblue}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

% my specific environment
\newenvironment{myalign}
{
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybluebox]{align}
}
{\end{empheq}}


\begin{document}

% my test
\begin{myalign}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{myalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here use `\empheq` and `\endempheq` instead of `\begin{empheq}` and `\end{empheq}`

Comment: Thank, you it is working.